# How to make Wordpress generate a description meta tag on post tag list pages?

Tags: seo, wordpress

Wordpress 6.3.1, Rank Math SEO plugin

ahrefs Site Audit flagged an Error of "Meta description tag missing or empty" for all our Wordpress tag list pages.  For example, the public showcase linked from wordpress.com has the page https://wordpress.org/showcase/tag/cms/ which lists posts with the tag 'cms', but this page has no `<meta name="description">` tag on it.

I know this is relatively trivial, but an ahrefs error is an ahrefs error :)

How can I get Wordpress to include a sensible `description` meta tag on these pages?

I'm a competent PHP developer but completely new to the Wordpress implementation, so have no idea where to start looking.  Is there an option somewhere, or do I need to modify some PHP code?

[image: Screenshot of ahrefs error]

Answer (score 1):

You can add description for tags. Go to tags and try to edit the tag. There you can see the option to add description. That description will fetch as meta description.

Comment: Brilliant, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome  @Neek . Glad to hear it helped.